# How to create a new user account with WiX?

Tags: wix

I have made a bootstrapper-project with WiX 3.8, including an installation file (WXS) for the prerequisite SQL Server Express.
In the InstallCommand-Property of the ExePackage, which i'm using for the installation of SQL Server Express, i set /SQLSVCACCOUNT and /SQLSVCPASSWORD.
So i need to create the user account before the installation of the prerequisite.

How and at which place shall this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [User element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/user.html) in the [Util extension](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/).

If you are unsure about how to use elements defined by extensions, read the [How To: Use WiX Extensions](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/general/extension_usage_introduction.html) topic.

This information is also in a CHM that is installed by the WiX installer in the WiX program files folder.

Comment: Thank You Wim for Your answer.

Comment: I tried it with the User-element but get a privilege error.
Maybe You can take a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27481096/getting-privilege-error-while-creating-a-new-user-and-adding-it-to-the-administr