# Getting privilege error while creating a new user and adding it to the administrators

Tags: wix

I have a made a setup-project with WiX 3.8 in which i want to create a new user and add it to the administrators group.
But each time my setup comes to that point, i get an error because of insufficient privileges.
That's a little bit curious, because my user is an administrator on the virtual machine, on which i test the setup.
What can i do?

That's the code in the WXS-file for creating the user:

```
<util:Group Id="Administrators"
            Name ="Administrators"
            Domain="[ComputerName]" />
<Component Id ="CreateUserAccount"
           Guid="AEE91491-99FA-40A9-AB47-1E9FC2DDEF2A"
           Directory="TARGETDIR">
    <util:User Id ="SQLUser"
               Name="[MyUsername]"
               Password="[MyPassword]"
               UpdateIfExists="no"
               CreateUser="yes"
               PasswordNeverExpires="yes"
               PasswordExpired="no"
               RemoveOnUninstall="no"
               Domain="[ComputerName]">
        <util:GroupRef Id ="Administrators"/>
    </util:User>
</Component>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of [UAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control), a process must still elevate its privileges even if the user is an administrator. This gives the user a chance to deny the elevation of privileges at the security prompt.

In the [Package](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/package.html) element, make sure you have set `InstallPrivileges="elevated"`. This should ensure that Windows Installer prompts for elevated privileges during the installation.